Is there any way to get Ambient Occlusion in Geometry Nodes?
I want to be able to get Ambient Occlusion like in Shader Graph, but only in geometry nodes

I don't know if there's anything more recent, but Curtis Holt did a YT video about it around 2 years ago.
